# C - Trouble calling a function

Tags: c, base64

With the following code, I'm trying to encode a string to a base 64. I couldn't figure out how to call the method.

I'm trying to convert the input string `"test"` to `"dGVzdA=="` in base64.

I've tried using `strcpy(data,txt)`, but couldn't figure out how to complete the method call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char encoding_table[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
                                'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
                                'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X',
                                'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
                                'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
                                'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
                                'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3',
                                '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/'};

static int mod_table[] = {0, 2, 1};

char *base64_encode(char *data,
                    size_t input_length,
                    size_t *output_length) {

    *output_length = 4 * ((input_length + 2) / 3);

    char *encoded_data = malloc(*output_length);
    if (encoded_data == NULL) return NULL;

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < input_length;) {

        uint32_t octet_a = i < input_length ? (unsigned char)data[i++] : 0;
        uint32_t octet_b = i < input_length ? (unsigned char)data[i++] : 0;
        uint32_t octet_c = i < input_length ? (unsigned char)data[i++] : 0;

        uint32_t triple = (octet_a << 0x10) + (octet_b << 0x08) + octet_c;

        encoded_data[j++] = encoding_table[(triple >> 3 * 6) & 0x3F];
        encoded_data[j++] = encoding_table[(triple >> 2 * 6) & 0x3F];
        encoded_data[j++] = encoding_table[(triple >> 1 * 6) & 0x3F];
        encoded_data[j++] = encoding_table[(triple >> 0 * 6) & 0x3F];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mod_table[input_length % 3]; i++)
        encoded_data[*output_length - 1 - i] = '=';

    return encoded_data;
}

int main() {
  char txt[] = "test";
  char *data;
  //... Please help 
}
```

How can I convert `txt` (`"test"`) to `"dGVzdA=="` and print it?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you have with your attempt?

Comment: Unclear. Read [ask] and provide all required information. Also C does not support _methods_. Copy&paste is not **programming**.

Comment: I'm new to C ... I couldn't figure out the basics, I've tried using strncpy to copy the data to the pointer, but got lost

Comment: Not knowing how to call a function means you have copied all this code and don't know anything about C. I suggest you start with a book on C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `main()` that calls `base64_encode()`:

```
int main(void) {
  char data[] = "test";
  char *encoded_data;
  size_t len;

  encoded_data = base64_encode(data, strlen(data), &len);
  printf("%s (%zu) => %s (%zu)", data, strlen(data), encoded_data, len);
}
```

#### Explanation

- **`char data[]`** contains your string to encode. You'll need to pass it as an argument to `base64_encode()`.
- **`char *encoded_data`** is a pointer that you'll use to store the return value of `base64_encode()`. You will use this variable to access the decoded string, since `base64_encode()` returns a pointer to an allocated space where the decoded string is stored.
- **`size_t len`** is a variable that will be used to store the size of the decoded string. You'll give a pointer to this variable as argument to `base64_encode()`.
- **`strlen(data)`**, the second argument to `base64_encode()`, is the length of `char data[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should read a book or tutorial about C programming as calling functions is a very basic concept.

To answer your question pass the plaintext, it's length, and the address of a variable to receive the resulting output's length:

```
int main() {
  char txt[] = "test";
  char *data;
  size_t output_length;

  data = base64_encode(txt, strlen(txt), &output_length);
  printf("%*s\n", output_length, data);
}
```

The function returns a pointer to the data. In the code sample above that will be assigned to `data`. The length of the returned string will be set by the function in the `output_length` variable.

It's important to note that the returned string is *not* null terminated in `base64_encode()`. This can lead to problems later in your code if you were to assume that it is a null terminated string and tried to use it as such. For example naively printing it or trying to find its length with `strlen()` could result in a buffer overrun and possibly a program crash.

You could append a null character (`'\0'`) to `data`, however, `base64_encode()` allocates only enough space for the encoded string so strictly speaking appending anything could access invalid memory causing a crash. Solutions to this include:

- Treat the string with care. Print it with something like this:

  ```
     printf("%*s", output_length, data);
  ```
- Allocate your own string of length `output_length + 1` , copy the
  encoded string to the new string, then null terminate the new string:

  ```
     data = base64_encode(txt, strlen(txt), &output_length);
     char *encoded = malloc(output_length + 1);
     strncpy(encoded, data, output_length);
     encoded[output_length] = '\0';
  ```

Finally, be sure to call `free(data)` when you have finished with the base64 encoded data to ensure that the memory allocated in function `base64_encode()` is released.

Comment: Cool, I tried to printf the data but the compiler says:"format string is not a string literal "

Comment: You need to be careful with the encoded string because it will not necessarily be null terminated. You can safely print it with `printf("%*s\n", output_length, data);`